# What equivalant to window[funcName]() in web-worker JS?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

How can we write `window[funcName]()` in web-worker JS?

how access to function declared in top context of script ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The [tag:worker] tag says "Consider [tag:web-worker] for JavaScript" … are you talking about web workers? What do you mean by "The top context of the script"? Are you asking about the outer most part of the web worker or are you asking about a script loaded into the HTML page that has triggered the worker? Your example shows `funcName` as a variable, are you specifically asking about how to access different functions based on a variable? Or is that beside the point? You should provide a [mcve] showing how your code fits together.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:context] which is a Go language tag, what does that have to do with your question? (Seriously: **Read the details of the tags you are using** and make sure they are the correct tags!)

Comment: yes it's for web-worker. sry for misstake, I edit tag !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a `WebWorker` you can use [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self) to reference to the global scope (you could also use `this` (when it points to the global scope, exactly like it works for `window`):

```
// worker.js
function foo() {
  console.log("hello worker");
}

self['foo']()
```

Comment: I already try this but doest work. Maybe it's the coffeescript fault? when I writte `myFunction = -> 42` it's compiled to lambda function ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about coffeescript, the only thing I can suggest to you is checking the output code and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `window` object, that is actually the goal of `web-workers`

> The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface

A quote to the documentation will answer your question:

> workers run in another global context that is different from the
>   current `window`. Thus, using the `window` shortcut to get the current
>   global scope (instead of self) within a Worker will return an error.

But you have the `self` object that contains some built-in functionalities.